# Scaling screen sizes of web applications for different devices

Tags: html, cordova, screen, resolution

How do you properly scale a web application so that it is cross platform compatible. With so many different phones having different screen resolutions what is a good height/width I should aim for. What is the most effective way to do this scale?

If you don't understand my question: when you load a webpage on a phone it automatically scales it to be the full size of a web page, as opposed to having it zoomed in so you can properly see the text. How do you have it so it is automatically zoomed in.

Comment: The "Scaling web application" term has been used on server and application architecture, and therefore is misleading here. I think the appropriate question title should be "Scaling screen sizes of web applications for different devices", unless you're asking two different questions. You may find some information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) useful on responsive web design. Some resources [here](http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup/) and [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/) you may find useful as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you read about [Responsive Web Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design).

Quoting from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design): ***"Responsive web design (often abbreviated to RWD) is an approach to web design in which a site is crafted to provide an optimal viewing experience—easy reading and navigation with a minimum of resizing, panning, and scrolling—across a wide range of devices (from desktop computer monitors to mobile phones)."***

If you [search for it](https://www.google.com/search?q=responsive%20web%20design&rlz=1C1TSNP_enUS471US471&aq=0&oq=responsive%20web%20&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), there are hundreds of great articles.

Here's [a beginner's guide](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design).  There are also books on the topic.